# How many terms are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, multinomial-theorem

Consider the expansion: $$(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)^4$$
 How many different terms are there in this expansion? Actually the problem is I can not apply the multinomial theorem because it comes same factors from the  product of different terms, I mean for example $x^2 × x^5$ gives $x^7$ and also $x^3 × x^4$ gives $x^7$. How can I control to count all distinct terms only once? How can I generalize this example for any number of $x$'s and any positive integer powers?

Comment: It has terms $x^8$ through $x^{24}$ so17 terms.  The only concern is is there any power of $x^i$ not created.  As you have any sum a+b+c+d where {a,b,c,d}={2.... 8} the answer is pretty easily verified that you can.  With the binomial theorem it is pretty easy to find the precise terms but since you didn't ask for that I won't.

Comment: Note that it's the same as $x^8$ times the fourth power of a six degree polynomial. How many terms are in the fourth power of a six degree polynomial?That will be your answer.  Note that no powers are omitted.

Comment: In general the terms will be the number of sums.

Comment: @fleablood: where are you getting $x^4$ and $x^{24}$ as the terms of lowest and highest degree? the correct boundary terms are $x^8$ and $x^{32}$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic because everyone knows 4x2 = 4 and 4x 8 = 24 of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All combinations of terms $x^ix^jx^kx^l$ where $i,j,k,l = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8$.  As all combinations can and will be done these can and will be as low as $8$ and as high as $32$.

The real question is what will the coefficients be.  And the answer to that is that the coefficient of $x^m$ will be the number of ways to solve $i+j+k+l = m$ with $2,3,4,5,6,7,8$.  Which is the number of ways to solve $i+j+k+l = m -8$ with $0....6$.

Comment: Wait but if we choose $i, j, k, l \in [6]$, then $m = i + j + k + l + 8$, so the number of ways to choose $m \in [6]$ is zero, right?

Comment: The number of ways to choose i+j+k+l=11 where 2<= i,j,k,l <= 8 is 19: 2+2+2+5;2+2+3+4;2+2+4+3;2+2+5+2|2+3+2+4; 2+3+3+3; 2+3+4+2| 2+4+2+3;2+4+3+2|2+5+2+2|3+2+2+4;3+2+3+3;3+2+4+2|3+3+2+3; 3+3+3+2|3+4+2+2|4+2+2+3;4+2+3+2;4+3+2+2;5+2+2+2;  The number of ways to choose i+j+k+l=3 where 0<= i,j,k,l <=6 is also 19. 0+0+0+3;0+0+1+2;0+0+2+1;0+0+3+0 etc.  They are the same sums but with 2 removed from each term so the total is eight lower.

Comment: As low as eight (2+2+2+2) and as high as 32 (8+8+8+8) so 25 values is equivalet to as low as zero (0+0+0+0) and as high as 24(6+6+6+6) and the sums i + j +k + l = m are equivalent to (i-2) + (j-2) + (k-2) + (l-2) = m-8 and that can be solve in the same number of ways.